# Android HTTP request always returns code 404

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a simple HTTP request. The request will verify a username and password from a server. The server is configured such that it will only return two error codes, 200 for verified and 404 for everything else. I've done extensive debugging with eclipse and found that I always receive code 404. I've read all other existing questions before posting this.

```
private class loginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
    String check;
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                ("http://www.unite.upmc.edu/account/IPhoneLogin?username=username&password=password

        String username = arg0[0];
        String password = arg0[1];
        URI uri = null;
        try {
            uri = new URI("http://unite.upmc.edu/account/IPhoneLogin?"+"username="+username+"&"+"password="+password);// I know the method is called IPhoneLogin, it's being used by both Android and IOS clients
        } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        try {//Look here

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet(uri));
            String code = "" + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            check = code;
            if(code.equals("200")){
                loggedIn = true;
            }else{
                                    //need to re-enter username and password
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        hasPin = false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... integers) {
        setProgress(integers[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(UniteActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Logging in...." + check);
        dialog.show();

    }
```

I know the server is up and the password and username are correct because I've logged in normally many times using internet explorer. I'm using the eclipse IDE with Android SDK and am concerned this might be a product of the buggy emulator it provides. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 404 is NOT FOUND... This error comes because the URL is either wrong, or the server os setup incorrectly

Comment: Try checking in the emulator's web browser to see if you can access the URL. IIRC, the emulator network doesn't necessarily have access to the same DNS server as your local network. For example, running the emulator on my work machine I can't access our internal sites through the web browser or any apps. Since I can't access your http://www.unite.upmc.edu URL from my machine, this may be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in doInBackground method to get response code

```
url = new URL(mUrl);

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, url+"");
            HttpGet method= new HttpGet(new URI(mUrl));
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(mUrl));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(method);
            responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Hopefully this will work fine.